# kendo UI issues with Jasmine test cases

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

We have used Kendo UI with HTML5 and JSON file. For unit testing have written Jasmine test cases.When have applied kendo widgets for more controls but the second one is coming as undefined.

```
describe("Test cases", function () {
   beforeAll(function (done) {
       //Called Load method of a page 
   });

   it("Test Grid data", function (done) {
       var grd = jq("#grdOne").data("kendoGrid");
       var row = grd.dataSource.data();

       //tested row
       done();
   });

   it("Test Phone number", function (done) {
       var $Phone = jq("#txtPhone").data("kendoMaskedTextBox");//$Phone is Undefined
       done();
   }); 
});
```

If I am changing the sequence of 2 specs then the First one gets executed.An i.e grid will come Undefined and $Phone will contain a value after changing the sequence of the test case. The First case has been written after Load() gets executed successfully and the second one fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In kendo, if you load the widget twice then masking will be removed. 
So for than while loading check whether the masking applied or not.

```
    it("Test Phone number", function (done) {
        var $Phone = jq("#txtPhone");
      if(!$Phone.data("kendoMaskedTextBox")) {
            $Phone.kendoMaskedTextBox({
                mask: "000-00-0000"
            });
        }
        $Phone.data("kendoMaskedTextBox").enable(true);
    }
    );
```

For more details check link :
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-common-issues